# Any Interactive Geometry Tools Online?

Tags: geometry, math-software

I'm looking for an online tool that will let me draw lines and circles etc on a plane and then tell me the positions of any intersections, the size of any angles formed and potentially lengths of formed arcs.

Does anyone know of one?

Comment: You can try Geogebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/YhMm8vgX). Is free, easy-to-use and has all features you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best free software which is very close to your request:
http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/download.html